# Laravel 4 pagination with Bootstrap 3

Tags: pagination, laravel, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I using the pagination into a bootstrap 3 app and there is something wrong.
This is how i call the pagination:

```
$newsletterUsers = NewsletterUser::paginate(2);
```

And then after the foreach loop i put this:

```
  {{ $newsletterUsers->links() }}
```

That's all right?
but instead of showing the normal nice laravel pagination,
there the numbers one over the other, without style, and are even not paginated correctly since it paginate with 1 - 1 - 2 elements and not 2 - 2 as it should be

And this is the html markup:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <ul>
<li><a href="---/public/newsletterConfirmedUser?page=2">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li><a href="---/public/newsletterConfirmedUser?page=1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="---/public/newsletterConfirmedUser?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span>3</span></li><li class="disabled">
    <span>&raquo;</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: You should add the `pagination` to the `<ul>` instead of the container `div`. I don't understand what should be 2-2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel currently only works with bootstrap 2's pagination but you can use a workaround for now until bootstrap 3 is supported.

First create a view that will use bootstrap 3's pagination syntax by making a new file at "app/views/pagination.php"

**app/views/pagination.php**

```
<?php
        $presenter = new Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapPresenter($paginator);
?>

<?php if ($paginator->getLastPage() > 1): ?>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?php echo $presenter->render(); ?>
        </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then open up the file **app/config/view.php**

and near the bottom you will see a line that reads

```
'pagination' => 'pagination::slider',
```

which you can change to read

```
'pagination' => 'pagination',
```

Now you should be able to use laravels pagination as you normally would.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Now i see the normal pagination.
But there is still something wrong, if there is paginate(2); 
I see 4 pages with 1 - 1 - 2 elements.
If there is paginate(3); there 1 - 3 - 0 elements.
If there is paginate(4); there 2 - 2 elements.
Wtf is going on?

Answer (score 18):

When you look into the laravel 4 core framework's Paginator, you will see in the view folder *vendor/laravel/Illuminate/Paginator/views* a file called slider-3.php! This view uses the bootstrap 3 paginator

```
<?php if ($paginator->getLastPage() > 1): ?>
<ul class="pagination">
        <?php echo $presenter->render(); ?>
</ul>
```

Knowing this, you simply change the paginator in the app/config/view to

```
    'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',
```

And done.